# LangDetect what is profile?

Tags: java, detection, profile

I am currently searching how to recognize tweets languages. I found the apache library tika but it doesn't work well...
Now, I have found langdetect and I am trying to use it.
Currently, I have found a sample of code but I don't understand what is the file "profiles"... I don't know what I need to put inside...

```
String path = "my path to the file profiles";
                DetectorFactory.loadProfile(path);
                detector = DetectorFactory.create();
                detector.append(tweet);
                langDetected = detector.detect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/blob/wiki/Tutorial.md#initialize-library):

> Before using this library, call `DetectorFactory#loadProfile()` once to initialize.
>
> `DetectorFactory.loadProfile(profileDirectory);`
> The parameter of this method is a directory which has files of language profiles. **The language profiles are bundled with this library, so specify `"trunk/profile"` in repository as the parameter of `loadProfile()`.**

Profiles files are in the repository in the [`profiles` subdirectory](https://github.com/shuyo/language-detection/tree/master/profiles)

Comment: Thank you! It works. I just needed to extract profiles from the jar files.